# Store Data out from Angular Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs-observables

I wanted to store the data from the angular observable method. I'm checking one condition where if the parameter value that is email is same as the data I'm retrieving from the backend then the observable method should return the Id of the same entry.

**Below is the code I've tried**

```
hrId:number=0;
currentUserEmail = 'a@a.com';

  getCurrentUserId()
  {
    this.service.getHrDetails().subscribe(data=>{
      for(const d of data)
      {
        if(d.email == this.currentUserEmail)
        {
          console.log("Correct");
          this.hrId=d.id;
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

**In the console I'm getting the result but I'm not able to store the value in the hrId variable, that is outside of this method**

[Result of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqv6Z.png)

**I just wanted to store the value that I got after comparing the result in the hrId variable outside of this method so that I can use it elsewhere also.**

Comment: You're aware that observables are asynchronous? And you're probably logging your value of `this.hrId` synchronously?

Comment: Hey Robby, I'm new to Angular and observables , Can you please help me in this?

Comment: "Store data" Does this mean you have a store to place the data? If no then try looking into ngrx. This will let you store the value and then you can use it on demand in your application. Otherwise SessionStorage/localStorage will help you.

Comment: By storing the data I meant is I want to store the value of d.id that is 2 in this case to hrId.

Answer (score 2):

Observables are asynchounous, you should create a method that returns an observable of the ID. then you can subscribe or create an async pipe.
here is an example:

```js
assignHrId() {
  this.getCurrentUserId(this.currentUserEmail).subscribe(
    id => {
      if (typeof id !== 'undefined') {
        this.hrId = id;
      } else {
        console.log('No data found for email: ', this.currentUserEmail);
      }
    }
  );
}

getCurrentUserId(emailToCheck: string): Observable<number> { // returns an observable
  return this.service.getHrDetails().pipe(
    map(dataArray => dataArray.find(d => d.email === emailToCheck)), // returns the correct data
    map(d => d?.id) // returns the id or undefined if no data was found with that email
  )
}
```

Comment: I want to store the value in HrId variable, don't know how to store the value by using your solution, can you tell me how to store value in the particular variable HrId? Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "store the value" ? As you can see in my example inside the subscribe you have `this.hrId = id;`.  There you save the value inside `hrId`.